# Show that $f$ is 1-1

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, almost-everywhere

Let $f$ holomorphic, $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$.

If $w\in\mathbb{D}$ we denote as $n_f(w)$ the number of zeros of the function $f(z)-w$. If $n_f=1$ almost everywhere in $\mathbb{D}$, show that $f$ is $1-1$ in $\mathbb{D}$.

My thoughts: I know that the set $\{w\in\mathbb{D}:n_f(w)\neq 1\}$ has zero measure which means that this set is measurable but I have no idea on how to proceed with this problem.

Any useful hints or a solution would help me very much as I'm struggling a lot with problems at that level of complex analysis.

Comment: Idea: construct a suitable cycle that winds around two distinct points equal to $w'$ under $f$, then apply Argument Principle, but this implies all points in a ball around $w'$ with winding number $\geq 2$...

Comment: show that if $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$ then for $y_1$ close enough to $z_1$ there is $y_2$ close enough to $z_2$ st $f(y_1)=f(y_2)$ hence $n_f \ge 2$ on an open set (because $f(B_{z_1}(r)=D_1(r)$ an open set containing $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$ and so is $f(B_{z_2}(r)=D_2(r)$ hence there is a small open set containing $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$  in the intersection

Comment: $f$ may not be onto as there may be points in the image for which $n_f=0$ (for example one can have an injective holomorphic map from the unit disc onto a slit unit disc, where $n_f=0$ on a segment);